# Many duplicate "Github wants my password" questions. Can a moderator please merge them?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, merged-questions

There are many identical "Why is github asking me for my password, even though I have setup my ssh-keys?" questions open right now.

1. Jul 2011 [Git push requires username and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565357/git-push-requires-username-and-password?lq=1)
2. Oct 2011 Answered [Git keeps prompting me for password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773181/git-keeps-prompting-me-for-password)
3. Sep 2013, Answered, same as 1. [Still requiring login after SSH authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18797940/still-requiring-login-after-ssh-authentication)
4. Jul 2014 Answered, same as 1.: [SSH Key - Still asking for password and passphrase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21095054/ssh-key-still-asking-for-password-and-passphrase)
5. Nov 2014 [git push asks for username and password when pushed to shared private repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26826986/git-push-asks-for-username-and-password-when-pushed-to-shared-private-repository)

These seem to all be exact duplicates in questions and answers, and should be merged.

Many of them have more than 100 upvotes.

When I posted this last year, I flagged for mod attention, but was declined as I was told to "just vote to close", but I feel rather than closing and marking as duplicated, as multiple have great answers. they should be Merged, which is a diamond mod only power (right?)

Comment: Side note: Should these be on Super User instead of Stack Overflow?

Comment: Use of programmer tools is on topic here

Comment: I only ask because Super User has the same issue with the similar question. [[1](http://superuser.com/q/364131/72528), [2](http://superuser.com/q/199507/72528), [3](http://superuser.com/q/538680/72528), [4](http://superuser.com/q/827292/72528)]

Comment: This is certainly an overlap between SU and SO :)

Comment: And yet I see people saying GitHub-related questions belong on Webapps.SE.  (I don't particularly care where they go, just as long as we don't fragment our knowledge base and communicate clearly with askers.)